# Android: is it possible for a broastcast message to be lost between orientation change?

Tags: android

If I have an Activity and a BroadcastReceiver, and I call registerReceiver in onCreate and unregisterReceiver in OnDestroy, could a broadcast message be 'lost' when the activity is destroyed and not yet recreated during an orientation change?

Answer (score 1):

> could a broadcast message be 'lost' when the activity is destroyed and
>   not yet recreated during an orientation change?

Yes. For most cases, you will get an exception or warning. You should not register your BroadcastReceivers to your activity. Do something like

```
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver()
```

See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/inN1ez8sftg) link.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for broadcasts to occur between tear down and recreate of your activity. If your receiver is not registered at the time of a specific broadcast, yes, the activity will miss that broadcast. You should read through the [BroadcastReceiver reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), if you haven't already. Here's the relevant quote:

> Note:    If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume()
>   implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You
>   won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on
>   unnecessary system overhead).

With that said, if you need to always catch a particular broadcast, you should register your receiver using [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) in your app's manifest, rather than in the activity onCreate.

For example, this receiver will listen for device boot up regardless of whether the app or activity is currently running:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```